# Stop browser from adaptively selecting an image interpolation algorithm

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms, image-scaling

During a transition (or animation) which scales an element using `transform`, Chrome (and perhaps other browsers) abruptly change the way they interpolate image pixels.

Before and after the transition, Chrome uses a high quality interpolation that looks smooth, while preserving sharpness. But during the animation, it abruptly switches to a lower-quality algorithm that makes the image look slightly blurred, which is presumably an optimisation to keep the framerate high.

In my case, this abrupt switch is obvious and undesirable. **Can I use css to request that the browser doesn't do this optimisation?**

The css property `image-rendering` doesn't seem to have any property to "force" high-quality rendering (the default, `auto`, is the only high quality setting). Firefox has an `optimizeQuality` setting which is probably what I want, but this isn't supported by webkit/blink.

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution with good coverage of modern browsers, although IE9-era browsers can miss out.